# Flutter Firesbase is returning Null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('dutyStatus');

Future<void> readOnDutyStatus() async {
//The function is being called in the authentication bloc
try {
  List status = [];
  // await db.add({'onDuty': true});
  var data = await db.doc('driver1').get();
  var temp = data.data();
  status.add(temp);
  print(
      '_______________________________________________________________________________________');
  print(status.toString());
  print(
      '_______________________________________________________________________________________');
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

The result :
I/flutter (25466): _______________________________________________________________________________________

I/flutter (25466): [null]

I/flutter (25466): _______________________________________________________________________________________

W/er_drive_mobil(25466): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/er_drive_mobil(25466): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)

Note: The same code when used on another account of firebase works as intended and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: What is "driver1"? Is this your doc id reference? How does your "driver1" look in Firebase? Please attach a screenshot

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so I couldn't upload a screenshot. driver1 is the document name that has a value pair of {onDuty: true}.

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXfYkiCZI7vcQubATRngB2vUxSEjhA9t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A link of the picture, which contains the structure of driver1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely driver1 doesn't exist.

Try this

```
var temp =  data.exists ? data.data() : "Doc does not exist";
```

Print list should return `[Doc does not exist]` instead of null.

Check if there is a white space before driver1 i.e _driver1 or after it. Otherwise there's no other explanation.

Comment: Yeah this prints [Doc does not exists] but it is there in firebase.

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXfYkiCZI7vcQubATRngB2vUxSEjhA9t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check if there is a white space before `driver1` i.e _driver1 or after it. Otherwise there's no other explanation.

Comment: Yeah there was a whitespace fixed the issue thanks for the help

Comment: You're most welcome, please consider marking it as a correct answer to your post.